# How to find elements that have some attribute NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'd like to find rows in my table that have end_date NULL or not present.

I am not sure how to do this with PostgreSQL nor could I find any useful examples online. I am using Rails though.

I tried sth like:

```
   Tag.where("end_date IS ?", nil)
```

and also

```
 Tag.where("end_date IS NULL")
```

Without success. The above returns all the tags that exist which is wrong. Maybe I should do it sth like

```
 Tag.where("end_date IS NOT DATE")
```

I'd appreciate any answers!

Comment: You say "end_date NULL or not present", what does "not present" mean? What type is your `end_date` column? Can you show us some sample data? Using `end_date is null` should find you all the rows with a NULL `end_date`.

Comment: #<Tag id: 1912, start_date: "2014-04-02", end_date: nil, description: ""

Comment: Meaning no value is assigned to this attribute.

Comment: It looks like all the versions are correct. I was misguided because I saw 1200 and something matching tags that have end_date NULL. And thought it must be wrong. But as I see now my database was a bit corrupt. Thank you for taking time to look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash in `where()`:

```
Tag.where({ end_date: nil })
```

Comment: It looks like all the versions are correct. I was misguided because I saw 1200 and something matching tags that have end_date NULL. And thought it must be wrong. But as I see now my database was a bit corrupt. Thank you for taking time to look at it!